# Emulator doesn't show up in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, emulation

Emulator preview doesn't show up giving this error.
[image]

Also tried building the project.

Comment: Build a project once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was trying to fix mine a while ago, I saw a lot of answers saying to drop the API to 21 (provided your getting this error on API 22)

Changing the theme to Halo.Light worked for me as well though